# Objective-C my callback function return message two times

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, callback

First of all sorry about my poor english. I want to post facebook with web dialogs. But before post, I check some information (is facebook account link another user etc.). And as you seen I'm doing this with callback functions. I want if facebook account was linked another user, callback "NO" and "error message". My view controller when recieve message, I close active session. But when I close active session,

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_about_me",@"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

   else if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
      if (callBack) {
        callBack(NO,@"Session closed");
      }     
   }
}];
```

(in openFacebookSessionForRead method) triggered and then callback to "postWithFacebookAccount" method. And then "postWithFacebookAccount" method callback to myviewcontroller "NO","FacebookError" so I show two alert to user.

I don't want this. And I must close session. I don't know what to do. I hope I could explain the problem.

## My Codes

### FacebookManager.m

```
-(void)postWithFacebookAccount(FBManagerBoolResultCallBack)callBack{
    [self openFacebookSessionForRead:^(BOOL success, NSString *message) {
        if (success) {
            [self getUserFacebookInfo:^(NSDictionary *userFacebookData, NSString *message) {

                if (userFacebookData) {
                    PFQuery *query = [Adw_UserSession query];
                    [query whereKey:@"facebookId" equalTo:[[userFacebookData objectForKey:@"id"]description]];
                    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            callBack(NO,@"FacebookLinkAnotherAccount");
                        }
                        else{
                            //....
                        }
                    }];
                }
                else{
                    callBack(NO,@"FacebookError");
                }
            }];
        }
        else{
            if ([message isEqualToString:[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Message_FBLogin"]]) {
                callBack(NO,[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Message_FBLogin"]);
            }
            else{
                callBack(NO,@"FacebookError");
            }
        }
    }];
}


- (void)openFacebookSessionForRead:(FBManagerBoolResultCallBack)callBack{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    }
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_about_me",@"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

        if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
            if (callBack) {
                callBack(YES,@"Session opened");
            }
        }
        else if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
            if (callBack) {
                callBack(NO,@"Session closed");
            }
        }
        else{
            if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
                if (callBack) {
                    callBack(NO,[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Message_FBLogin"]);
                }
            }
            //.....
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        }
    }];
}
```

### MyViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)act_facebook:(id)sender {
        FacebookManager *fbManager = [[FacebookManager alloc] init];
        [fbManager postWithFacebookAccount:YES parameters:nil withCallBack:^(BOOL success, NSString *message){
            if (success) {
                //...
            }
            else{
                if ([message isEqualToString:[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Message_FBLogin"]]) {
                    [Common showAlert:message title:@""];
                    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                }
                else if ([message isEqualToString:@"FacebookLinkAnotherAccount"]) {
                    [Common showAlert:[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Facebook_Link_Another_Account"] title:@""];
                    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                }
                else if ([message isEqualToString:@"FacebookError"]) {
                    [Common showAlert:[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Facebook_Error"] title:@""];
                    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem

```
    - (void)openFacebookSessionForRead:(FBManagerBoolResultCallBack)callBack{
           if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
    __block BOOL recursion = NO;
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_about_me",@"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

    if(recursion) {
     return;
    }
    recursion = YES;
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        if (callBack) {
            callBack(YES,@"Session opened");
        }
    }
    else if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        if (callBack) {
            callBack(NO,@"Session closed");
        }
    }
    else{
        if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
            if (callBack) {
                callBack(NO,[LanguageManager localizedString:@"Message_FBLogin"]);
            }
        }
        //.....
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: Thank you. I add bool variable to: @implementation FacebookManager{BOOL recursion;} and I set recursion before callback in postWithFacebookAccount method. it worked. Thank you for help